# What could be the reason for the error "SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY"?

Tags: android, kotlin

Good afternoon, I am writing an application for working with the network on jetpack compose using a clean architecture, and I encountered an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`
```

Gradle project

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.1.1'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
```

Gradle module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.kotlinretrofit'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kotlinretrofit"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.0-alpha04"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"

    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
}
```

As I understand it, this error is related to dependencies, but all dependencies were taken from a 10-day-old video. I tried to omit the gradle version, but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution to the problem turned out to be adding

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.2"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is, you have added `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` library two times and both have different version , may be this will be the reason.

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"
```

keep the `2.5.1` version and remove `2.3.1`

Comment: the solution to the problem turned out to be adding
`
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.2" 
`